# Encountered problems using luajit and fii libraries

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit, .so

In LuaJIT, the so is loaded through the fii library, and the functions in the so are called, but in the loaded so, the variables used by some methods are defined through extern. For example, the actual definition of this structure is in another so file. At this time, loading so will report undefined symbol: how to solve this problem?

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

print("start test:")
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/data/system2.so"

ffi.cdef[[

typedef enum
{
    E_DEBUG_LEVEL_ERR,
    E_DEBUG_LEVEL_WARNING,
    E_DEBUG_LEVEL_NOTICE,
    E_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFO,

    E_DEBUG_LEVEL_MAX
}DebugLevel_E;


typedef enum
{
    COMRET_SUCCESS              = 0,
    COMRET_INTERNAL_ERROR       = 1,
    COMRET_INVALID_ARGUMENTS    = 2,
    COMRET_RESOURCE_EXCEEDED    = 3,
    COMRET_LOCK_TIMEOUT         = 4,
    COMRET_MAX
} ComRet;

typedef void json_object;

extern  g_eDebugLevel;

ComRet Reboot(json_object *jsonSend);
]]

 local example = ffi.load("/data/system2.so",true)

 local jsonSend = ffi.new("json_object")

local ret = example.Reboot(jsonSend)

if ret == ffi.C.COMRET_SUCCESS then
  local jsonString = 
ffi.string(ffi.C.json_object_to_json_string(jsonSend))
   print("JSON Object content:", jsonString)
else
   print("Reboot failed or invalid return value")
end
```

Comment: BTW, `package.cpath` is not used by `ffi.load`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the actual definition of this structure is in another so file

FFI is unable to read structure definitions from so files.
You must explicitly specify your structure in full details in `ffi.cdef` argument.
Usually this could be done by adapting the definition from your header file.

You can define an opaque struct (by specifying forward declaration which lacks definition)

```c
typedef struct json_object json_object;
```

It is enough for receiving such an object created somewhere else, but you will be unable to create object of this type with `ffi.new`.

Sometimes it is enough to create a memory block (for example, `ffi.new"uint64_t[1000]"` or something like that) large enough to fit the object which structure is unknown.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the way you said, I have verified and passed it.

Comment: At present, I have another problem. When I call a function in so in this way, the parameter of this function is a json_object, and the function is to fill the data into this json_object. When the content of this json_object is only some int or other types, I can successfully call this function and get the content of this json_object. When the json_object parameter contains another json_object, calling this function will directly cause luajit to crash

Comment: I have searched for a long time, but there is too little relevant information. Do you have any suggestions for this, thank you very much. If other friends know or understand, please let me know, thank you very much

Comment: If you are interested in this, the code is wrong and reported above, thank you for your selfless help